# XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience

Tags: javascript, signalr

Eu uso biblioteca SignalR, para enviar ou receber as notificações.

Segue código:

```
$(function () {    
    // Start hub
    $.connection.hub.start().done();  // <----Aqui faz ele aparecer no console
});
```

Console log:

> XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its
>   detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check
>   https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Quando comento a linha:

```
//$.connection.hub.start().done();
```

O aviso no console desaparece.

Qual é a causa desse aviso e como corrigir ?

**OBS:** jQuery versão 3.1.1 e SignalR versão 2.2.2, versão mais atualizada pelo nuget.

Comment: Consegues criar um jsFiddle que reproduza esse problema? Sugiro colocares no Github como issue. Não estou a ver qual o problema possa ser se essa biblioteca usa o jQuery 3.

Comment: @Sergio, quero muito fazer isso em jsFiddle, tem parte do C# lado servidor precisa fazer ela funcionar o signalR. Como posso fazer ?

Comment: Não dá para usar o echo do jsFiddle? que simula o servidor